# How do one remove a muscle pain relieving patch or sticker without picking up leg hair?

Tags: comfort

How do one remove a muscle pain relieving patch or sticker without picking up leg hair? Or at least relieve the pain of picking? It is really painful.

Comment: Is the patch comparable to a regular (albeit larger) bandaid?

Comment: It is more sticky and thick, with a thick layer of sticky glue material that contains pain relieving medicine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the adhesive is similar to a Band-Aid adhesive, baby oil will work. It dilutes and neutralizes the adhesive. You can either coat the patch with baby oil, or try rubbing / dribbling baby oil up underneath the patch to contact the adhesive. As you slowly pull the patch off, keep rubbing the baby oil against the exposed adhesive near your skin.

(BTW baby oil is just mineral oil with fragrance, so if you have any mineral oil that's just as effective.)

I believe olive oil works pretty well in the same way, if you don't have any baby oil.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your information. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Rubbing alcohol is one option for removing the sticker. Simply dampen that with the alcohol, then wait a few minutes while the fluid dissolves the glue.